# android:hardwareAccelerated state of my application

Tags: android

How to get the value of hardwareAccelerated of my application in code ? How to modify it through code ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Window w = activity.getWindow();
w.setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_HARDWARE_ACCELERATED,
WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_HARDWARE_ACCELERATED);
```

The above code will do the same as android:hardwareAccelerated="true"

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the answer given above: Canvas.isHardwareAccelerated()/View.isHardwareAccelerated() returns true if canvas/view is hardware accelerated. For more information see http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/hardware-accel.html